# Inherit session token between 2 apps as long as one of them has been signed in Ember.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, ember.js, token

I have 3 web apps written in ember.js /appA, /appB and /AppC in the same domain and they connect to the same api with a token.

I have this configuration:

```
// under app/session-stores/application.js

import AdaptiveStore from 'ember-simple-auth/session-stores/adaptive';

export default class ApplicationSessionStore extends AdaptiveStore {
  cookieName = 'appX'; // where X is {A, B or C}, in every app respectively
  localStorageKey = 'appX';
}

// Without this file a user can log in whatever app and share his token to the others apps.
```

Whit this setting every user have to login for each app.

How can I make a user log in from /appC without using username and password as long as this user has already logged in from /appB?.

Thanks in advance beautiful people.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same cookie and local storage names in appC and appB and the session will be shared.

Comment: Tanks for the info, I already probe that trick, but what I need is that If some user log in /appC (at the begining), then that user will  have to log in /appB (if he needs to do some stuff after).

This is because not all people who have credentials in /appC should to watch info from /appB.